# A semigroup with only one idempotent element is not a group counterexample.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, semigroups

A semigroup with only one idempotent element is a group.

This statement is false. Let $A$ be the set of all non-negative integers.
For a counterexample, I take $(A,+)$.
In the semigroup $(A,+)$, there is only one idempotent element. That is, $0$ since $0+0=0$. In particular, $0$ is the identity element in $(A,+)$.
But, $(A,+)$ does not form a group since it does not contain an inverse for all $x \in A$. That is, there is no $y \in A$ such that for all $x \in A, x+y=0$.

Is the counterexample above true?

Comment: Yes, it's fine.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Noted. Thanks sir.

Comment: For another (even simpler) example, take any set $A$ with more than one element, choose an element $e\in A$, and define $xy=e$ for all $x,y\in A$.

Comment: What @bof described is called null semigroup (since the $e$ acts like zero, and any two elements get absorbed into it). It provides a (trivial) example to multiplicative structure of rings. Any commutative group is a ring using null semigroup as multiplication.

Comment: For another example, take any infinite set $E$ and consider the semigroup of all injective maps $f:E\to E$ with the operation of composition.

Comment: The correct version of that statement is: if $G$ is a group, then $G$ has only one idempotent element. And so the opposite implication indeed does hold.